# Error in reading 4 dimensional data from EXCEL to GAMS

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a 4-dimensional data in Excel as follows.

1. Row 1: Set **a** with 2 elements, */'Refinery 1','Refinery 2'/*
2. Row 2: Set **b** with 2 elements, */'Pipeline','Rail'/*
3. Column 1: Set **q** with 2 elements, */'Warehouse 1','Warehouse 2'/*
4. Column 2: Set **r** with 3 elements, */'Petroleum','Diesel', 'Jet Fuel'/*.

[My data looks like this in Excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lC3A.jpg)

I try to import the data from **Excel** to **GAMS** by the following code.

```
sets  a  first row entries
      b  second row entries
      q  first column entries
      r  second column entries

parameter data3(a,b,q,r);

$CALL GDXXRW.EXE i=Try1.xlsx o=Try1.gdx  set=a rng=Sheet1!A3:A6 rdim=1 set=b rng=Sheet1!B3:B6 rdim=1 set=q rng=Sheet1!C1:H1 cdim=1 set=r rng=Sheet1!C2:H2 cdim=1 par=data3 rng=Sheet1!A1:F6 Rdim=2 Cdim=2

$GDXIN Try1.gdx $LOAD a,b,q,r,data3 $GDXIN

display data3;
```

It shall produce the resulting parameter, i.e **data3** as *24 elements* (2x2x2x3), But it only shows *16 elements*, due to some problems and ignores other elements.

[The resulting GDX looks like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8LYn.jpg)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question about mathematics, so this forum is not really appropriate.

But to answer your question, easier is:

```
sets  a  first row entries
      b  second row entries
      q  first column entries
      r  second column entries

parameter data3(a,b,q,r);

$CALL GDXXRW.EXE i=Try1.xlsx par=data3 rng=A1 Rdim=2 Cdim=2 trace=2
$GDXIN Try1.gdx
$LOAD a<data3.dim1,b<data3.dim2,q<data3.dim3,r<data3.dim4,data3

display a,b,q,r,data3;
```

If you want to stick with your approach use `dset` instead of `set` in the call to gdxxrw.